# Fill a image in a cell excel using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to add a resized photo into a excel file using openpyxl module for python i am using the following code but didnt work... only adds the photo (not resized) from the specified cell.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

img = Image.open('photo.jpg')
nimg = img.resize((140,92))
img=openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('photo.jpg')
ws.add_image(img, 'F2') #where F2 is the cell where i want to add the photo

wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

I also tried to open the image with PIL but when i want to give the resized image as a parameter i`ve got some errors..

```
import openpyxl
from PIL import Image
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

img = Image.open('photo.jpg')
nimg = img.resize((140,92))
final=openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(nimg) #i think here i got some errors
ws.add_image(final)
wb.save('test.xlsx')

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/uidn4858/Desktop/Task2/sc.py", line 29, in <module> new=openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(nimg, 'F2') File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.4.9-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\drawing\image.py", line 54, in __init__ self.format = image.format.lower() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Please always post your error along with your question.

Comment: Just gussing - can you try this - `ws.add_image(nimg , 'F2')` instead of your `ws.add_image()` on your first try?

Comment: @Vityata, just tried and got this error  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/uidn4858/Desktop/Task2/sc.py", line 29, in <module>
    new=openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(nimg, 'F2')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.4.9-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\drawing\image.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.format = image.format.lower()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
from PIL import Image

width = 23
height = 23

img = Image.open('photo.jpg')
img = img.resize((width,height),Image.NEAREST)
img.save('photo.jpg')

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('photo.jpg')
ws.add_image(img,'F10')
wb.save('out.xlsx')
print('ready')
```

---

This works, if you consider the following:

- New workbook is created;
- `Photo.jpg` is changed in the original file;

Comment: ty for your answer, but i did it, i want to make this without creating another photo, is this posible?

Comment: @PaulNovac - see the edit. Anyway, it is usually a better practice to save the file under a new name when it changed.

Comment: i also find this solutin, but this solution will overwrite the initial photo with the risezed photo, nvm i will give you the green check for helping me, ty :)

Comment: @PaulNovac - in general I guess that one has only 2 options - either overwrite or save as a new one. What is the 3. option you are thinking of? You may also make a new photo, use it and delete it, but it is a variant of the second one.

Comment: i would like to open a photo from a path for example `img = Image.open('photo.jpg')`, `resize 'img = img.resize((width,height),Image.NEAREST)` and then to reuse that image `nimg = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(nimg)` and in the final to add the photo `ws.add_image(nimg,'F10'')`

Comment: @PaulNovac - well, the code above does pretty much this, but without assigning 2 variables to the image... Or am I wrong?